# Position of the first character of the second line of content editable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a `div` with content editable enabled:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
  est laborum.
</div>
```

If I type a lot of text in this div, the text is visually displayed on two lines (no line break character was entered). I want to detect the position of the first character of the second line.

Is there a way to get this position from Javascript?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh boy that's difficult. I think you could use an HTMLCanvasRenderingContext2D element to measure the text width for each character and check when it surpasses the contenteditable's clientWidth, making that a potential candidate for the second line. This would ignore the pre- line breaks as well, however. Maybe someone else knows of a better way, that's why I'm leaving this as a comment. But this would be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! Would you have a sample of this approach?